# Encrypt/Decrypt specific data in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I'm new to PHP, and I'm developing a web app for one of my subjects in college. The web app consists in platform to book nature activities. 
My problem is in one of the requirements, "encrypt/decrypt data", in which I need to encrypt the credit card data before it goes to the DB. 
For simplicity, the credit card fields are in the reservation table. 
This is my code:

```
$fieldsReservation = array(
    'idUser' => $idUser,
    'idActivity' => $idActivity,
    'reservationDate' => $reservationDate,
    'state' => 'reserved',
    'cardName' => $cardName,
    'cardType' => $cardType,
    'cardNumber' => $cardNumber,
    'cardExpiry' => $cardExpiry,
    'cardCVV' => $cardCVV);

$password = '3sc3RLrpd17';
$method = 'aes-256-cbc';

// password must be exact 32 chars (256 bit)
$password = substr(hash('sha256', $password, true), 0, 32);

// IV must be exact 16 chars (128 bit)
$iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);

foreach ($fieldsReservation as $key => $value){
    $fieldsReservation[$key] = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($value, $method, $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
}
```

I already have tried with a `foreach`, but with a `foreach`, all data is encrypted, and i just want to encrypt the credit card data. 
If anyone could help me, I would be grateful!

Comment: It's nice to know that a newcomer encrypts the credit cards and saves them to the database, and I appreciate that decryption key you included. What's the URL to your  project again? Asking purely out of curiosity.

Comment: By **reusing the key and IV** you can be absolutely certain that the result is not as secure as it should be. Even more importantly, a password is not the same as a key, and SHA-256 is not a good Password Based Key Derivation Function. So even if code *works*, your code is *not secure* which is goal of encryption after all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears you would like to encrypt only the fields that contain card-related data, such as `cardName`, `cardType`, `cardNumber` etc. How about this:

```php
foreach ($fieldsReservation as $key => $value){
  if (substr($key, 0, 4) == "card") {
    $fieldsReservation[$key] = 
      base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($value, $method, $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
  }
}
```

By looking at the each key, the code checks to see if it starts with "card". If so, its gets encrypted.

Comment: Oh, I never thought that way, using substr "card", but it makes sense. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Downvoted as this answer doesn't spot the security issues and I don't want to upvote any answer containing insecure code.

Answer (score -1):

Create a list of fields you want to encrypt, and just loop through that.

```
$to_encrypt = ['cardName', cardNumber'];

foreach ($to_encrypt as $key ){
    $fieldsReservation[$key] = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($fieldsReservation[$key], $method, $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
foreach ($fieldsReservation as $key => $value){
  $fieldsReservation[$key] = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($value, $method, $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
}
```

Just use

```
$fieldsReservation['cardNumber'] = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($fieldsReservation['cardNumber'], $method, $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
```

The foreach loops through every element of the array, so it SHOULD encrypt every element of the array. If you want to work with one specific element of an array, only do something to that one element of the array.

Comment: Partial answer at best, all card fields need to be encrypted.